# error in electron js when implementing express js

Tags: node.js, express, electron

I'm trying to build a desktop application using electron js .I want to integrate express js in my application .when I try to start my application,I'm facing this error

```
[Main Instruction]
A JavaScript error occured in the browser process

[Content]
Uncaught Exception:
Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:814:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:837:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1214:14)
    at listen (net.js:1250:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1340:5)
    at EventEmitter.listen (C:\Users\Kobbi\WebstormProjects\untitled14\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:617:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Kobbi\WebstormProjects\untitled14\index.js:17:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:428:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:446:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:353:32)'
```

here is my code:

```
var BrowserWindow = require('browser-window')
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});






var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;

  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});




app.on('ready', function() {
  var mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600
  })
  mainWindow.loadUrl('http://localhost:3000')
})
```

I would appreciate any help ,thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

`app.on('ready')` ... 'app' is not your express app.
this should be electron app.

Example:

```
var app = require('app');
BrowserWindow = require('browser-window');
express = require('express');
expressApp = express();
```

May be express use 'app' variable and electron also uses it.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the EADDRINUSE error means, that your port is already beign used (probably by an instance of your express webserver). Maybe your electron app didn't close properly, and you have to kill to manually to also kill the webserver that is accessing the port.